# Ativar botão de download em js

Tags: javascript, html, validação

Eu tenho um formulário que requer que seja preenchido o nome e email para fazer download de um ficheiro. Mas não entendo o suficiente de js para desativar o botão de download até que os outros campos estejam válidos, ou seja, de momento o botão funciona e faz download, independentemente dos campos de nome e email  estarem ou não preenchidos.

Alguém me sabe dizer se é possível fazer com que o download só seja realizado se os outros campos estiverem preenchidos?

Botão no HTML:

`<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='download/CV.pdf'">Download</button>`

JS:

```
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var error_message = document.getElementById("error_message");

  error_message.style.padding = "10px";

  var text;
  if(name.length < 5){
    text = "Please Enter valid Name";
    error_message.innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }
  if(email.indexOf("@") == -1 || email.length < 6){
    text = "Please Enter valid Email";
    error_message.innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }
  alert("Obrigado!");
  return true;
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

No onclick podes apontar para uma função js que contém o teu código. Aí em vez de return true podes usar o mesmo código que tens atualmente no onclick do button.

Algo do género (não testado):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="downloadFile()">Download</button>

function downloadFile(){
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var error_message = document.getElementById("error_message");

  error_message.style.padding = "10px";

  var text;
  if(name.length < 5){
    text = "Please Enter valid Name";
    error_message.innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }
  if(email.indexOf("@") == -1 || email.length < 6){
    text = "Please Enter valid Email";
    error_message.innerHTML = text;
    return false;
  }

  alert("Obrigado!");
  window.location.href='download/CV.pdf'
}

}
```

Comment: Obrigado Pedro, a tua ideia pareceu me bastante boa, ao testar tudo funciona, mas não chega a dar trigger ao download. Deve ter algo a ver com o ``` window.location.href ```, secalhar funciona em HTML mas não no JS.

Comment: Para essa parte do código vê este post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832662/4966284 , acho que te pode ajudar

Comment: O window.location.href é mesmo javascript, não sei porque não está a funcionar. Talvez ter o alert antes esteja a impedir que esse código não seja executado, mas pode ser outra coisa qualquer. Experimenta usar o código do post que te enviei. Vai ser criado um elemento html anchor(<a>) com o link do ficheiro; é feito o click nesse elemento disparando o download do documento e elimina de seguida elimina o elemento.